# Reverse Polarity Protection p-channel mosfet

Tags: mosfet, reverse-polarity

I am trying to design a basic reverse-polarity protection circuit using LTspice but I am not sure what values to use. The input voltage is 12 V, 100 ohms resistor and a 10 V Zener diode.

What is the best P-channel MOSFET to use with this design? Any change to the current values is acceptable.

Reference circuit design:

[image]

Comment: What MOSFET to use would greatly depend on what exactly the load is going to be.

Comment: i just want to check the input vs output voltage in the simulation, there won't be a need for a load in the design! @Unimportant

Comment: If there is no load, then there is no "best".  Any p-channel power MOSFET should work in the simulation.  If the input voltage is guaranteed to be below +/-20 V, then you don't need the zener.